# Convert seconds to age in 3rd column of csv file

Tags: bash, awk, seconds

3rd column of a comma delimited csv file contains seconds that I would like to convert to age. (sample data below). I'm using bash to generate these reports and want to convert the seconds to age like 10d 3h 20min 30sec or similar. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

```
28126265
6678363
3182862
11401914
1029092
9655690
34381431
13126178
2516335
```

Comment: are you looking for a script or a one liner?

Comment: A one liner that I can add to my existing script would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Perl:

`perl -F, -ane 'printf "%dd %dh %dm %ds\n", int($F[2]/(24*60*60)), ($F[2]/(60*60))%24, ($F[2]/60)%60, $F[2]%60' file`

`-a` autosplits each line to array `@F`
`-F,` autospits each line using commas as the separator
Since Perl arrays start at index 0, the 3rd element is `$F[2]`

input:

```
a,b,28126265,d,e
a,b,6678363,d,e
a,b,3182862,d,e
a,b,11401914,d,e
a,b,1029092,d,e
a,b,9655690,d,e
a,b,34381431,d,e
a,b,13126178,d,e
a,b,2516335,d,e
```

output:

```
325d 12h 51m 5s
77d 7h 6m 3s
36d 20h 7m 42s
131d 23h 11m 54s
11d 21h 51m 32s
111d 18h 8m 10s
397d 22h 23m 51s
151d 22h 9m 38s
29d 2h 58m 55s
```

Since you want to preserve the existing data:

`perl -F, -ane 'printf "%s,%dd %dh %dm %ds,%s", (join ",",@F[0..1]), int($F[2]/(24*60*60)), ($F[2]/(60*60))%24, ($F[2]/60)%60, $F[2]%60, (join ",",@F[3..$#F])' file`

`@F[0..1]` is an array slice of the first two elements of array `@F`
`$#F` is the index of the last element of array `@F`

output:

```
a,b,325d 12h 51m 5s,d,e
a,b,77d 7h 6m 3s,d,e
a,b,36d 20h 7m 42s,d,e
a,b,131d 23h 11m 54s,d,e
a,b,11d 21h 51m 32s,d,e
a,b,111d 18h 8m 10s,d,e
a,b,397d 22h 23m 51s,d,e
a,b,151d 22h 9m 38s,d,e
a,b,29d 2h 58m 55s,d,e
```

Or alternately:

`perl -F, -ane '$F[2] = sprintf "%dd %dh %dm %ds", int($F[2]/(24*60*60)), ($F[2]/(60*60))%24, ($F[2]/60)%60, $F[2]%60; print join ",",@F' file`

Comment: This does exactly what I want. It keeps all the other columns intact while formatting the 3rd column... Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution. But not a oneliner.

```
time=28126265
m=60
h=$((m * 60))
d=$((24 * h))
nd=$((time / d))
rt=$((time % d))
nh=$((rt / h))
rt=$((rt % h))
nm=$((rt / m))
rt=$((rt % m))
echo ${nd}d ${nh}h ${nm}m ${rt}s
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a one liner unless you are willing to use Perl or Python.

In awk, (which I am not great at) here is a solution.

Given:

```
$ echo "$ages"
28126265
6678363
3182862
11401914
1029092
9655690
34381431
13126178
2516335
```

You can do:

```
echo "$ages" | awk '{
t=int($0);
days=int(t/(24*60*60));
t-=days*24*60*60;
hours=int(t/(60*60));
t-=hours*60*60;
minutes=int(t/60);
seconds=int(t-minutes*60);
printf("%dd %02dh %02dm %02ds\n", days, hours, minutes, seconds);}'
```

Prints:

```
325d 12h 51m 05s
77d 07h 06m 03s
36d 20h 07m 42s
131d 23h 11m 54s
11d 21h 51m 32s
111d 18h 08m 10s
397d 22h 23m 51s
151d 22h 09m 38s
29d 02h 58m 55s
```

Comment: I can manage something like this. My issue is that this data ($ages in your example) is part of a large report. Its the 3rd column in a csv file. So I need a way to change that data in place or write to a new file but still keeping the rest of the report..

Comment: Im not sure I understand what your asking. But Im using a bash script to combine 3 different reports (created by a performance app) then massage that data before sending it out to users.

Comment: I tried extracting the data and using your solution to format it, but I can not get it back into the 3rd column correctly. The awk line im using to replace the old data with the formatted data from the temp file is removing all of my commas and Im not sure why. I know there is an simpler way to accomplish this...

awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," }; FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$3=a[FNR] }1' ./temp/agesconv.csv ./reports/PROD_Age_Report.csv

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
awk -v FS="[,]+" '{days=$3/86400;hours=(days-int(days))*24;minutes=(hours-int(hours))*60;seconds=(minutes-int(minutes))*60;print int(days)"d",int(hours)"h",int(minutes)"m",int(seconds)"s"}'
```

here is the breakdown

```
awk -v FS="[,]+" '{
days=$3/86400; #find floating value for days
hours=(days-int(days))*24; #minus floating value from rounded value and multiply by 24 to get floating value for hours
minutes=(hours-int(hours))*60; #minus floating value of hours from rounded value and multiply by 60 to get floating value for minutes
seconds=(minutes-int(minutes))*60; #minus floating value of minutes from rounded value and multiply by 60 to get floating value for seconds
print int(days)"d",int(hours)"h",int(minutes)"m",int(seconds)"s"
}'
```

output

```
325d 12h 51m 4s
77d 7h 6m 3s
36d 20h 7m 41s
131d 23h 11m 53s
11d 21h 51m 32s
111d 18h 8m 10s
397d 22h 23m 50s
151d 22h 9m 37s
29d 2h 58m 55s
```

Comment: note i use $3 for awk to work on your seconds in column 3 in your file